# GPU no signal output, installing driver (on integrated card) causes system freeze

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, power-supply, gpu

I recently decided to build a budget PC, I bought the following parts:

- MOBO: Gigabyte Z170-HD3P
- CPU: Intel I3-6100
- GPU: Asus R9 280x
- PSU: Cougar RS750 v3, 750W
- RAM: HyperX 4GB DDR4

I've plugged the PSU -> GPU power and both green led over the plugs are green, so I suppose the power is OK. I also tried moving the GPU between the 2 PCIEs. I tried resetting BIOS, different versions of drivers, but it hadno effect.

Here is what I got so far:

- Without GPU plugged in, everything works as expected.
- With GPU plugged in, but the HDMI connected to the integrated card (and  forced through BIOS), the system boot, but when I try to install the driver, everything freezes

  - With GPU plugged in and HDMI in GPU, I get no signal from the monitor (all fans work)
  - Device manager (in windows 10) was detecting the card as "microsoft basic video driver", tried to manually force auto drive update, but didn't find the proper drivers.

What might be causing the problem? Is my GPU faulty?

Comment: Boot to BIOS with the Graphics Card plugged in and disable all the integrated video outputs, and see if Windows will display at boot with generic driver without crashing. Then be sure you are using the latest version of the [drivers for the card from the manufacturer's website](https://www.asus.com/us/Graphics-Cards/R9280XDC2T3GD5/HelpDesk_Download/), so download, install and then reboot and see if all is good. Be sure to also double check the GPU card to see if it needs any voltage wires going to it to give full power of all video output ports... just double check in case.